# Calling schedule () function on an RTOS application

Tags: c, schedule, rtos

I am pretty naive to the concept of RTOS, so this question might also be naive :)

While reading about task scheduling in RTOS, i came across the concept that the a non preemptive task can be interrupted if it calls `schedule()` (On linux based RTOS).

I need to know how actually this function can be called from the c program\application\task? An example will help.

Comment: Pretty sure the author of the text you're reading didn't mean `schedule()` as a C function, but meant that the scheduler might have the chance to start executing something else, if he gets the chance, i.e. when the current task (which pretty much is synonymous with process on Linux) yields control or an interrupt of some sort occurred.

Comment: Understood, but the idea behind RTOS is the user\programmer can have more control over the scheduling, so are you saying there is no way in RTOS that a user make a task non preemptive and then permit switching as and when required?

Comment: That's a completely different question!

Comment: But yes, of course a process can allow for another task to take over.

Comment: otherwise, that non-preemptive task would be the only thing that could ever be executed on a single-CPU machine, right?

Comment: may be i framed my earlier question in a wrong way, but yes i want to know how can a process allow another task to take over, or permit the scheduler the allow the interference.

Comment: yes. That's easy. Basically, every syscall does that; and  the proper way to do it definitely depends on what you're logically doing, but it could for example be something like waiting on `read()` to complete.

Comment: that is correct but i believe this is similar is any traditional OS as well, so how does the programmer has more control in case of RTOS.

Comment: That depends on the actual RTOS. Linux itself isn't an RTOS at all – there are -preempt patches, but I don't think they change the API itself.

Comment: Notice that I'm no expert in Linux-preempt; I do think you should probably read up on some more simplistic RTOS theory before diving into the very complex Linux OS

Comment: (1) The preemptive kernel is an alternative to the standard Linux kernel.  The RT patches are completely different.  (2) *"how can a process allow another task to take over..."* -- A Linux process/thread can relinquish the remainder of its excecution time slot by calling **yield()**, which is the basis of cooperative processing (instead of competitive processing).

Comment: I would venture to suggest that "linux based RTOS" is an oxymoron.  It's either Linux or its an RTOS not both - even with PREEMPT.